# Advice on filtering GCP Cloud Storage event notifications, based on an object's prefix, when triggering a GCP Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, events, triggers, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Currently, I am moving services from AWS to GCP. Previously, I relied on an AWS S3 bucket and the inbuilt service's logic to configure event notifications to get triggered when an object with a particular prefix was inserted into my bucket. This specific event notification, which contained the prefix, would then be fed forward to trigger a lambda function.

However, now I have to leverage GCP Cloud Storage buckets and trigger a Cloud Function. My observations so far have been that I can't specify a prefix/suffix as part of my Cloud Storage service's bucket directly. Instead, I have to specify a Cloud Storage bucket to monitor during the creation of my Cloud Function. My concern with this approach is that I can't limit the bucket's object events to the three of interest to me: '_MANIFEST' '_PROCESSING' and '_PROCESSED' but rather have to pick an global event notification type of interest to me such as 'OBJECT_FINALIZE'.

There are two viable approaches I can see to this problem:

1. Have all the 'OBJECT_FINALIZE' event notifications trigger the Cloud Function and filter out any additional objects (those which don't contain the prefix). The issue with this approach is the unneccessary activation of the Cloud Function and the additional log files getting generated - which are of no inherent value.
2. Use the audit logs generated by the Cloud Storage bucket and create rules to generate events based on the watched trigger file i.e. '_MANIFEST', 'PROCESSING' and 'PROCESSED'. My concern with this approach is that I don't know how easily it will be to forward all the information about the bucket I'm interested in if I'm generating the event based on a logging rule - I am primarily interested in the information which gets forwarded by an event notification. Also, currently I have verified that the object being added to my Cloud Storage bucket is not public and I have enabled the following:
   [image]

However, I tried to filter the audit logs in the GCP 'Monitoring' service (after adding a _MANIFEST object to the bucket of course) but the logs  are not appearing within the 'Log Explorer'.

Any advice on how I should approach filtering the event notification of interest in GCP, when triggering my Cloud Function, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can sink the Cloud Storage notification into PubSUb.

Then, you can create a PubSUb push subscription to your Cloud Functions (it's no longer a background functions triggered by Cloud Storage event, but and HTTP function trigger by HTTP request.

The main advantage of doing that is that you can specify a filter on PubSub push subscription that allow you to activate your Cloud Functions (or any other HTTP endpoint) only with the pattern is enforced.

Comment: The approach you suggested is perfect for my use case however, I'm noticing the push notification is not actually triggering Cloud Function it is mapped to. I am simply testing the subscription service without any filter logic also, so I would expect the push notification to trigger my Cloud Function without issue. Any ideas why the message might not be getting pushed / triggering the execution of my Cloud Function?

Comment: It's a simple HTTP call to an HTTP Cloud Functions. The signature and the deployment of the Cloud Functions is slightly different.

Comment: Can you configure a Cloud Function to accept a pub/sub event (by specifying a specific push notification subscription which has been created) rather configurating the Cloud Function to accept a HTTP request? I performed a quick test around this and observed that I could only map my Cloud Function to a specific topic directly rather than from a subscription.

Comment: The PubSub event is wrapped in a HTTP Post request. It's also the case when you plug directly the Cloud Functions on your PubSub topic, except that the message is de-encapsulated by the Google Layer and sent to your function in RAW mode.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there must be a Google Layer that unwraps the HTTP message. However, does the Cloud Function consider the pub/sub subscription if at creation it could only reference a pub topic directly? I didn't have the option when creating my Cloud Function, to map it to a particular subscription. When I was creating a Cloud Function that accepts a HTTP request as input, I didn't have to specify any topic but rather the pub/sub subscription, on creation, could reference an endpoint to push the event to.

Comment: Cloud Functions create automatically a subscription when you deploy it (you can have a look to your subscription, they start by gcf)

Comment: I see that a subscription that starts with the 'gcf' was created alright however, I can't reference it when creating my Cloud Function it seems. I expect that I'll be left with no choose but to reference the pub topic directly when creating my Cloud Function so - this won't include the filter logic then. Unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: No, you are right. That's why, the way to achieve this is to create an HTTP function and a PubSub push subscription that invoque your function.